# What is the word for when somebody is lying, yet they believe someone else telling a similar lie?

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-requests

For example - let's say that Guy A is actually a 45 year old in his basement, but he pretends to be a young girl on a chat site. He meets Guy B, who claims to be a young boy, even though Guy B is also around 45 and is doing the same thing Guy A is.

Guy A will believe Guy B's lie, even though Guy A is doing the same thing, and Guy B will in turn believe Guy A's lie.

What is a word that could describe this sort of situation, if there is any?

Comment: it's called "ironic justice" or "serves them bloody right"

Comment: Sounds like a couple of conceited narcissistic morons.

Comment: _mutual gullibility_. If you want to apply this to your particular example, you could say _mutual [catfish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/catfish#Verb) gullibility._

Comment: Why can't they just go and kick a ball somewhere?

Comment: I don't think there's a common phrase for this, other than ironic, which is very general.

Comment: Lol at people looking for validation on these sites! An answer to this question won't solve a train wreck social situations.

Answer (score 1):

You may perhaps say:

**Both dupes and liars**

- *Dupe* definition from Cambridge dictionary : someone who has been ​tricked.

Answer (score -1):

Good luck getting all of that wrapped up in one word, but I'll offer this single-entry phrase:
***false hope***.

[CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/false-hopes) defines this as:

> *confident ​feelings about something that might not be ​true*

while the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=False+Hope) defines this as:

> *To look forward to something that has a strong chance of not happening and you may or may not know it*

Then there's this quote (found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope#In_psychology)), which contrasts *optimism* and *false hope*:

> Hopeful people are like the Little Engine that Could, [because] they keep telling themselves *“I think I can, I think I can”*. Such positive thinking bears fruit when based on a realistic sense of optimism, not on a naïve “false hope”.